# Microsoft word dot leader

Tags: microsoft-word

Working with microsoft word to create dot leaders for the table of contents. Somehow, I managed to create dot leaders.

[image: sample screen shot]

Problem:

My issue is to have double or multiple spaces between two adjacent dots. As dots are very compactly located, I wish to have some more spacing among them. Kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do the following:

Select all your dots. Go to Font (extend icon)->Advanced->Spacing->Expanded->In
(Select here the value to suit your needs).

I'm posting here a screenshot in Spanish (sorry for that) to give a cue for you.

[image].

Hope it helps! Kind regards.